# Reverse subparts of a contiguous linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a subpart of a singly-linked list where the subpart is a contiguous set of even elements, bordered by either the end of the list or an odd element.

So far, I know how to reverse a linked list but I'm unable to figure out how to check if the element is odd or if it's at the end.

```
  Node reverse(Node head) {
    // Write your code here
    if(head == null) return null;

    Node prev = null;
    Node curr = head;
    Node next = null;

    while(curr != null) {
      next = curr.next;
      curr.next = prev;
      prev = curr;
      curr = next;
    }
    return prev;
  }
```

Example
Input:
list = [1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 16]

Output:
[1, 8, 2, 9, 16, 12]

The subparts in this example are 2,8 and 12,16

Comment: *"if it's at the end"* You already know this. If `next` is null, then the `Node` is the last node in the list, i.e. it is at the end.

Comment: *"if the element is odd"* Really? You haven't been able to find *any* examples on the web for how to check if a value is odd or even. More likely you didn't even try, so question **down-voted for lack of research**.

Comment: just check if the modulo is 1 or 0. If it's 1, its an odd number. If it's 0, it's an even number. And I agree with @Andreas. You should do more research before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Node reverse(Node head) {
    if(head == null) return null;

    Node curr = head;
    Node next = null;
    Node prev = null;

    while(curr!=null && curr.data%2==0) {
      next = curr.next;
      curr.next = prev;
      prev = curr;
      curr = next;
    }

    if(curr!=head) {
      head.next = curr;
      curr = reverse(curr);
      return prev;
    } else {
      head.next = reverse(head.next);
      return head;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q. Given a singly linked list of integers, reverse every contiguous set of nodes that have only even values.**
**I/P** = 1 2 3 3 4 6 8 5, **O/P** = 1 2 3 3 8 6 4 5, **explanation** -
There are two sub lists of even elements, which [2] and [4->6->8]. The sub list [4->6->8] has been reversed and the single sub list [2] need not be reversed.
Test Cases passed
**1 3 8 3 4 2 6 5**   single/multi even element in list,
**2 4 6 1 3**         even occurs at head,
**1 4 4 6 8**         even occurs till tail,
**2 4 6 8 2**         all even in the list

```
import java.util.*;
//import ds.List.ListNode; import your ListNode class

/*
public class ListNode {
   public int val; 
   public ListNode next;
   public ListNode(int x) { val = x; next = null; }
}
*/

class Solution{

    public ListNode reverseEvenElements(ListNode head)
    {
      ListNode p = null;//prev
      ListNode c = head;//curr

      while(c != null){
         if(c.val % 2 == 0){
            ListNode start = p;
            while(c != null && c.val % 2 == 0){
               p = c;
               c = c.next;
            }
            //end of even elements = p
            //making end of even node to null so that reverse should stop 
//otherwise it will reverse whole list
            p.next = null;
            
            ListNode[] node;// [head,tail]
            // if start is null i.e. even element found at head itself
            if(start == null){
               node = reverseList(head);
               head = node[0];//node[0] = head of reversed list
            }else{// start != null 
               node = reverseList(start.next);
               start.next = node[0];
            }

            node[1].next = c;//node[1] = tail of reversed list
         }
         
         if(c != null){
            p = c;
            c = c.next;
         }
      }
      return head;
    }

   // this method will be called when even elements occurs till last even element we get 
//in the original list returns head & tail of reversed list
   public static ListNode[] reverseList(ListNode head){
      ListNode p = null;
      ListNode c = head;
      ListNode n = head.next;
      while(true){
         c.next = p;
         p = c;
         c = n;
         if(n == null)
            break;
         else 
            n = n.next;
      }
      
      return new ListNode[] {p, head};// [head,tail]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what you given me i understood like :
input : [1,2,4,8,5,7,7,6,6,2,8,1,1,1,2,4]
output: [1,8,4,2,5,7,7,8,2,6,6,1,1,1,4,2]
i have edited your code for reverse to reverse till which will reverse intervals & created reverse_whole which will find those intervals

```
public ListNode reverse_whole(ListNode head) {
    ListNode temp=head;
    ListNode pre_temp=new ListNode(0,temp);
    ListNode ans_pre = pre_temp;
    while(temp!=null){
        if(temp.val%2==0){
            ListNode temp_till=temp;
            while(temp_till!=null&& temp_till.val%2==0){
                temp_till=temp_till.next;
            }
            // temp_till will iterate over even number interval after one 
            //so: 1,2,4,6,7 : 7 is temp_till
            // reverse 2,4,6 so it become : 1,6,4,2,7
            pre_temp.next=reverse_subpart(temp,temp_till);
            temp=temp_till;
        }
        pre_temp=temp;
        if(temp!=null)temp=temp.next;
    }
    return ans_pre.next;
}
public ListNode reverse_subpart(ListNode head,ListNode end) {
    // Write your code here
    if(head == null) return null;
    ListNode prev = null;
    ListNode curr = head;
    ListNode next = null;
    while(curr != end) {
      next = curr.next;
      curr.next = prev;
      prev = curr;
      curr = next;
    }
    head.next=end;
    return prev;
}
```

run reverse_whole
if you have any doubt can write me

Answer (score -1):

```
class LinkedList { 
    Node head; 
    Node curr = head;
    Node next = null;
    Node prev = null;
    class Node { 
        int data; 
        Node next; 
        Node(int d) 
        { 
            data = d; 
            next = null; 
        } 
    }  
    
    void pairWiseSwap() 
    {    
        Node temp = head; 
        while (temp != null && temp.next!=null) { 
            int k = temp.data;
            int j = temp.next.data;
            if(k%2==0 && j%2==0) {
                temp.data=j;
                temp.next.data=k;
                temp=temp.next.next;
                continue;
            }
            
            temp = temp.next; 
        }
              
    } 
    public void push(int new_data) 
    { 
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data); 
        new_node.next = head; 
        head = new_node; 
    } 
    
    void printList() 
    { 
        Node temp = head; 
        while (temp != null) { 
            
            System.out.print(temp.data + " "); 
            temp = temp.next; 
        } 
        
        System.out.println(); 
    } 
    
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList(); 
        llist.push(16); 
        llist.push(12); 
        llist.push(9); 
        llist.push(8); 
        llist.push(2); 
        llist.push(1);   
        System.out.println("Linked List before calling pairWiseSwap() "); 
        llist.printList();   
        llist.pairWiseSwap(); 
        System.out.println("Linked List after calling pairWiseSwap() "); 
        llist.printList(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's better to add some details/explanation around your answer.